# Modify all the values in the column of a Pandas Series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a column with 9-char long numbers. I need to perform some operations on all values in that column to reach a length of 12. Here is the original data:

```
493    123456789
494    123456789
496    115098765
497    123456789
498    987654321
499    987654321
```

Now, I need to perform some modifications to the numbers:

- after the first 1, need to insert 20
- before the last 5 numbers, need to insert a 0

The desired solution is:

```
493    120234056789
494    120234056789
496    120150098765
497    120234056789
498    920876054321
499    920876054321
```

How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To double check: can we be sure there is a 1 in the second group of data? If not, then the final data will only be 10 digits long. So it seems we maybe missing a rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [indexing with str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str) for slice values:

```
s = df['col'].astype(str)
df['new'] = s.str[0] + '20' + s.str[1:-5] + '0' + s.str[-5:]
print (df)
           col           new
493  123456789  120234056789
494  123456789  120234056789
496  115098765  120150098765
497  123456789  120234056789
498  987654321  920876054321
499  987654321  920876054321
```

Similar solution with `apply`:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x[0] + '20' + x[1:-5] + '0' + x[-5:])
```

Performance for @Mark Wang:

```
#6k rows   
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [241]: %%timeit
     ...: s = df['col'].astype(str)
     ...: df['new1'] = s.str[0] + '20' + s.str[1:-5] + '0' + s.str[-5:]
     ...: 
19.5 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [242]: %%timeit 
     ...: df['new2'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x[0] + '20' + x[1:-5] + '0' + x[-5:])
     ...: 
11.4 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Second is faster, because pandas text functions are slower. One reason is, they correctly handle missing values.

Comment: The first one probably runs much faster

Comment: @erken - It connaot be converted, because `P` value in start of string `P20S20180807475`. So need set this values to `NaN`s ? Or remove all rows if wrong values like `P20S20180807475` ?

Comment: Good to see that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I noticed I had a strange value inside that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Jezrael, can you please remove your answer containing my error? :D or at least modify it, my mistake

Comment: @jezrael Didn't use the tag

Answer (score 1):

*Pure* regex alternative:

```
In [1067]: df[1].astype(str).replace(r'^(\d)(\d+)(\d{5})$', r'\g<1>20\g<2>0\g<3>', regex=True)
Out[1067]: 
0    120234056789
1    120234056789
2    120150098765
3    120234056789
4    920876054321
5    920876054321
Name: 1, dtype: object
```